# How to fix Reflection Exception Class validator does not exist error

Tags: php, class, laravel, service-provider, laravel-validation

I was recently working on some code and I got this error: Reflection Exception Class validator does not exist on line 20.

This is the last batch of code that has the error and is the desk service provider:

```
 /**
 * Register bindings
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->repositories();

    $this->app->bind('\Desk\Forms\MessageForm', function($app) {
        $validator = $app['validator']->make([], []);  (line 20)
        return new \Desk\Forms\MessageForm($validator);
    });
}

/**
 * Register Repositories
 */
protected function repositories()
{

    $this->app->bindShared('\Desk\Repositories\MessageRepository', function($app) {
        $record = new \Desk\Records\MessageRecord;
        return new \Desk\Repositories\MessageRepository($record);
    });
}
```

The service provider:

```
/**
 * Register bindings
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->registerSupport();
}
```

The controller:

```
protected $messageForm;

public function __construct(MessageForm $messageForm, MessageRepository $messageRepository,
  MessageRecord $messageRecord)
{
    $this->messageForm = $messageForm;
    $this->messageRepository = $messageRepository;
    $this->messageRecord = $messageRecord;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /messages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('message.create');
}
```

app.config

```
 'providers' => array(

    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',

    'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
    'Desk\ServiceProvider',
    'Desk\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Desk\Parts\PartServiceProvider',
    'Desk\Desk\Repositories\RepoServiceProvider',
    'Desk\Desk\Forms\FormServiceProvider',
    'Desk\Desk\DeskServiceProvider',
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that's the code for your custom provider. You should probably add it at the end of your `providers` section in `app/config/app.php` file and definitelly after `'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider'` because here is `$validator` created.

As I said go to `app/config/app.php` file and find section that begins with

`'providers'       => array(`

Now edit your providers list to put your provider at the end of your providers list:

```
'providers'       => array(

   // here all list of all default providers
   // here your custom provider
),
```

**EDIT**

You should then try to change:

```
$validator = $app->make('validator')->make([], []);
```

into

```
$validator = $app['validator']->make([], []);
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the beginning of the service provider where the error is occurring; e.g., it should begin with something like `use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider; class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {...` before the `register()` function.

Comment: I have updated the validator code and the providers and still getting the error any suggestions.

Comment: @will.i.am Yes, I saw, but I don't know how to solve it, sorry